# Rails domain-based caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

Rails caches (file cache) per default domain-based, but is there a way to disable this? My rails app can be reached via multiple domains and the content is all the same. I just don't want to have multiple cache files.

(I know memcache is better, this is not part of the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure an asset server in your `environment.rb`, so that all static files are loaded from the same domain.